# OrangeHRM Symfony(1.4) site moved from local to live server causing a page crash

Tags: symfony-1.4, orangehrm

I moved a site from local to live server. it is working just fine on local server but causing a page crash on live server. 
I have cleared the cache. Everything is just fine on local server and also on live server except a single page crash on live server with the error

**"An internal error occurred. Please contact your system administrator."**

when I check the logfile `orangehrm.log` inside `symfony/log` the following message appears

```
Thu 14 May 2015 12:29:13 PM GST,102 [1376] ERROR filter.ExceptionCatcherFilter - Uncaught Exception: exception 'sfRenderException' with message 'The template "ViewRequestSuccess.php" does not exist or is unreadable in "HERE SHOULD BE DIRECTORY NAME BUT IT IS EMPTY(THIS IS ADDED TO MENTION THE ERROR POINT)".' in /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/cache/orangehrm/prod/config/config_core_compile.yml.php:2029
Stack trace:
#0 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/cache/orangehrm/prod/config/config_core_compile.yml.php(3908): sfView->preRenderCheck()
#1 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/cache/orangehrm/prod/config/config_core_compile.yml.php(979): sfPHPView->render()
#2 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/cache/orangehrm/prod/config/config_core_compile.yml.php(966): sfExecutionFilter->executeView('performance', 'ViewRequest', 'Success', Array)
#3 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/cache/orangehrm/prod/config/config_core_compile.yml.php(934): sfExecutionFilter->handleView(Object(sfFilterChain), Object(performanceActions), 'Success')
#4 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/cache/orangehrm/prod/config/config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): sfExecutionFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#5 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/filter/sfCommonFilter.class.php(29): sfFilterChain->execute()
#6 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/cache/orangehrm/prod/config/config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): sfCommonFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#7 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/plugins/orangehrmCorePlugin/lib/filter/orangehrmPostExecutionFilter.php(22): sfFilterChain->execute()
#8 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/cache/orangehrm/prod/config/config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): orangehrmPostExecutionFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#9 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/apps/orangehrm/lib/filter/ModuleFilter.php(56): sfFilterChain->execute()
#10 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/cache/orangehrm/prod/config/config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): ModuleFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#11 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/plugins/orangehrmCorePlugin/lib/authorization/filter/ohrmAuthorizationFilter.php(97): sfFilterChain->execute()
#12 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/cache/orangehrm/prod/config/config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): ohrmAuthorizationFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#13 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/apps/orangehrm/lib/filter/SessionInfoFetcherFilter.php(67): sfFilterChain->execute()
#14 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/cache/orangehrm/prod/config/config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): SessionInfoFetcherFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#15 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/apps/orangehrm/lib/filter/OrangeI18NFilter.php(58): sfFilterChain->execute()
#16 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/cache/orangehrm/prod/config/config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): OrangeI18NFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#17 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/apps/orangehrm/lib/filter/ExceptionCatcherFilter.php(26): sfFilterChain->execute()
#18 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/cache/orangehrm/prod/config/config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): ExceptionCatcherFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#19 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/filter/sfBasicSecurityFilter.class.php(72): sfFilterChain->execute()
#20 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/cache/orangehrm/prod/config/config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): sfBasicSecurityFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#21 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/cache/orangehrm/prod/config/config_core_compile.yml.php(995): sfFilterChain->execute()
#22 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/cache/orangehrm/prod/config/config_core_compile.yml.php(1031): sfRenderingFilter->execute(Object(sfFilterChain))
#23 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/cache/orangehrm/prod/config/config_core_compile.yml.php(665): sfFilterChain->execute()
#24 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/cache/orangehrm/prod/config/config_core_compile.yml.php(2352): sfController->forward('performance', 'ViewRequest')
#25 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/util/sfContext.class.php(170): sfFrontWebController->dispatch()
#26 /var/zpanel/hostdata/some_app_name/public_html/hrm_something_com/symfony/web/index.php(22): sfContext->dispatch()
#27 {main}
```

I have added this line in above error message to mention the error point here. 
**HERE SHOULD BE DIRECTORY NAME BUT IT IS EMPTY(THIS IS ADDED TO MENTION THE ERROR POINT)**

after spending lot of time on debugging, I found out that on live server, it is not showing directory name i.e directory variable is empty. can anyone help that where should I change the setting/config or what can be the possible reason for this.

Comment: problem is 'The template "ViewRequestSuccess.php" does not exist or is unreadable... are you sure file exists? are you sure file have the correct name? including lower/upercase letters?

Comment: yes very sure.  I have double checked the directory manually, the file is there and its name is shown in `$this->template` variable in `config_core_compile.yml.php`. The name is also correct. however the template directory is not available in the `$this->directory` variable. same code is working fine on local server.

Comment: What should `$this->directory`contains? where is defined? Maybe a "routing problem"? your local server is Windows and the Live server is Linux? maybe a few screenshots of your filesystem would help? or maybe the controller code?

Comment: @Pipe `$this->directory` should contain absolute path to the template file. `$this->directory` is defined inside `config_core_compile.yml.php` file in cache folder in `abstract class sfView`. Every other page is working fine only one page is causing trouble. Yes my local machine is windows and live server is linux. If you are fimiliar with the `symfony(1.4)` then you will be aware that paths are built by symfony automatically and they are maintained in cache. I cleared cache after uploading my application on live server and every thing works fine just one page is craching.

Comment: I understood the problem... you can try using frontend_dev.php... maybe it throws a better error description.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the absolute paths of the old server and the new server are different. If this is the case, following steps will resolve the problem.

1. Delete the content in the `/oranghrm/installation/path/symfony/cache` directory.
2. In your command line, change the directory to `/oranghrm/installation/path/symfony/`
3. Run the command `php symfony cc`
4. Make sure that the http server has write access to `/oranghrm/installation/path/symfony/cache`, `/oranghrm/installation/path/symfony/logs` and /oranghrm/installation/path/lib/confs directories.